# HttpURLConnection connect to my google account

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to log into my google account using `HttpURLConnection`. I don't know  the right way to set it up, I am not sure it could be done with `java.net.*`, otherwise how should I proceed?

my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        URL myURL = new URL("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?user=***&pass=***");
        try
        {
            URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
            myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(myURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String str;
            while((str = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        catch(IOException x)
        {
            System.err.format("error %s%n", x); 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        System.err.format("error %s%n", x);
    }
}
```

The code displays my google login account content page instead of my account home page.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I doesn't display an error, it displays google authentication account page.

Comment: Where did you get the idea you could pass the username and password in the URL?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Maybe it would be better to use some of Google APIs?

Comment: I tried it by intuition, i also tried to use java.net.athentication but i've read on oracle tutos that it serve for setting up  authentication login from the server's side.

Comment: I really don't think Google would allow plain text passwords in a URL, do you?

Comment: Yes, i've seen that it was possible to do it with a google API, but i would like to know if it is possible with java and how does it work.  No you may be right, for google password plaintext, but it's the only way i thought using httpUrlConnection.

Comment: A quick google search gave me this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/

Comment: @hgoebi is right, though.  Google API is going to be the better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks , i'll watch that. My google parameters are set to french. I've not found this page !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google account to authenticate user, should use [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) protocol. Once you authenticate user , you could get user profile information or can access other Google API if you like.

In summary, if the user provides valid user/pass, you will get an authentication token that specifies this is a valid Google user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to programmatically connect to secure website, and getting past the login page, you might want to check out HtmlUnit Api.  Check out the bottom of the page on "Submitting a Form" for an example: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html